# mysqli returns simple query as object - why?

Tags: php, foreach

I'm having a simple problem understanding how to parse stdObject returns from simple queries with mysqli ... I've tried a couple of different ways to turn the stdObject into an array and also just using fetch_object() like here:

```
$cart_q = "SELECT card_name FROM products WHERE product_cat = 'HPC' LIMIT 12";
$result = $mysqli->query($cart_q);

echo "<table>";
$i = 0;
while ($products = $result->fetch_object()) {
   if($i == 0)
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>". $products->card_name ."</td>";
      $i++;
      if($i == 3) {
echo "</tr>";
$i=0;
     }
 }
 echo "<table>";
```

I've done a print_r of the object and gotten an associative array, but breaking it down to dislay within a page has yet to work ... any ideas?

Comment: To add, I've tried using both fetch_array() and fetch_row() but in those cases I still get an array for each record. I'm trying to get to the point where I return a regular array: [0]=>blah, [1]=>blabla etc ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note: I actually think your problem is with iterating over the result array, thus label should be php, or /and HTML, but let's see:*

Its usually good to separate retriving records from presentation, for example like this:

```
$mysqli = new MySQLi($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
$cart_q = "SELECT card_name FROM products WHERE product_cat = 'HPC' LIMIT 12";
$result = $mysqli->query($cart_q) or die($mysqli->error);

$card_names = array();
while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
    $card_names[] = $row['card_name'];
}
```

Above will create array `$card_names => array('card_name1', 'card_name2' ... etc)`

Now, you can use foreach to iterate over that array and create output HTML. From what I've understood you want to create HTML table with 4 cells per row and one card name per cell.

```
echo '<table><tr>';

$i = 1;
foreach ( $card_names as $name ){
    echo "<td>$name</td>";

    if ( $i % 4 == 0) echo '</tr><tr>';

    $i++;
}
($i - 1) % 4 == 0 ? echo '</tr></table>'; : echo '</table>';
```